# backbone.router and React states

Tags: javascript, reactjs, backbone.js, url-routing

What is the standard way of setting React Component states based on routes? I have the following React/Backbone example:

```
var myApp = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className={this.state}></div>
    );
  }
})

var App = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "": "home",
    "create": "create"
  }
});

var app = new App();
app.on('route', function(page) {
  // How do I set state on myApp??
})

React.renderComponent(<myApp />, document.body);
Backbone.history.start();
```

I believe I need to be able to set the state of `myApp` from outside, but how? I can’t find any examples on this.

Or maybe I’m thinking in the wrong direction here, is there a better way of organizing routes together with React?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

i have no idea what the general solution is, but what I, a bit simplified, did is

```
var App = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "": "home",
    "create": "create"
  }
});

var myComponent = false

function loadOrUpdateComponent(urlState) {
    if (!myComponent) {
        myComponent = <MyApp urlState={urlState}/>
        React.renderComponent(myComponent, document.body); 
    } else {
        myComponent.setProps({urlState:urlState})
    }
}


var app = new App();
app.on('route', function(page) {
  loadOrUpdateComponent(page)
})

Backbone.history.start();
```

So the actual answer to your question is to use `.setProps(newProps)` on a previously rendered component. i load the component in the event handler because else you get a race condition between renderComponent and setProps wich might lead to bad things.

Edit:

Ive since updated my route handling, i now simply do

```
router.on('list', function() {
    React.renderComponent(<Component data={someData} />, mountPoint)
})

router.on("details", function(id) {
    React.renderComponent(<Component data={someData} selected={id} />, mountPoint)

})

router.on("extra-details", function(id) {
    React.renderComponent(
        <Component data={someData} selected={id}>
            <SpecificExtraComponent />
        </Component>
        , mountPoint
    )
})
```

Comment: `React.renderComponent` will update an existing component if there is one, so your loadOrUpdateComponent function can simply be `React.renderComponent(<MyApp urlState={urlState />, document.body);`.

Comment: oh, neat. that makes it a bit simpler